# Rails: form doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I'm building a shopping cart and i have an issue with the following form:

```
<div id="produits-column-container">
<% if @produits %>
  <% @produits.in_groups_of(4, false).each do |g| %>
    <% g.each do |produit| %>
    <div id="produits-row-container">
      <div id="fiche-produit-container">
        <%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
          <div id="produit-img">
            <%= link_to produits_show_path do %>
              <%= image_tag produit.photo %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div id="produit-nom">
            <%= produit.nom %>
          </div>
          <div id="produit-prix">
            <%= number_to_currency(produit.prix, unit: '€', format: "%n%u") %>
          </div>
          <div id="produit-au-panier">
            <%= image_tag('icon/icon-panier') %>
            <%= f.submit 'Ajouter au panier' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When i run the server, the form doesn't appear in the view even though Rails doesn't raise any issue.
I don't understand why, any idea?

EDIT

here is my `produits_controller.rb` :

```
class ProduitsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @produits = Produit.all
    @order_item = current_order.order_items.new

    if @order_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @order_item, notice: 'Le produit a été ajouté au panier !' }
      format.json { render json: @order_item, status: :created, location: @order_item }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: "create" }
      format.json { render @order_item.errors, status: unprocessable_entity }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def show
    @produit = Produit.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Comment: aren't you missing the `@` in `<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>` -> `@order_item` ?

Comment: Make sure `@produits` is not empty. And one extra comment, you are repeating the ids of the divs, that's not correct HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line with `if @produits`.

With that line in place, the form will not show when `@produits` is empty.

Comment: the thing is, i have products added by an admin session so here produits is not empty... I have tried your solution and now i get this error: `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Then you've just answered the problem - `@produits` is `Nil`. Check your controller to see where `@produits` is created and filled

Comment: i have edited the question with `produits_controller.rb`