# Rails form doesn't display in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Similar to [Rails: form doesn't show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107645/rails-form-doesnt-show-up) post, I've run into a similar issue but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  the only thing in the view that shows up is the h1 "New User".

```
.container.mt-4
  %h1 New User

  = form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
    - if @user.errors.any? 
      #error_explanation
        %h2 #{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:
        %ul
          - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li %{msg
          .field
            = f.label :email 
            = f.text_field :email
          .field
            = f.label :password 
            = f.password_field :password 
          .field
            = f.label :password_confirmation 
            = f.password_field :password_confirmation 
          .action
            = f.submit
```

here's my users controller in admin

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to admin_users_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: [:admin,@user] }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Like in the other post, Rails no longer raises errors after I fixed the syntax errors it complained about.

Answer (score 1):

Because if your nesting, your form will only show up if user has errors.

I imagine you actually want something like this:

```
.container.mt-4
  %h1 New User

  = form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
    - if @user.errors.any? 
      #error_explanation
        %h2 #{pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this user from being saved:
        %ul
          - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li %{msg}
    .field
      = f.label :email 
      = f.text_field :email
    .field
      = f.label :password 
      = f.password_field :password 
    .field
      = f.label :password_confirmation 
      = f.password_field :password_confirmation 
    .action
      = f.submit
```